# how to change background color in scite (scintilla) editor

Tags: scintilla, scite

In frustration of some breakage, I've nuked my old/ancient
version of Scite, and done a fresh install of Scite.

So, on Windows, I now have 32-bit version 5.1.4.

Three issues:

#1 How/where to change the overall (not file-type specific)
background color, it defaults to WHITE. I'd like to configure it to that light-yellow-ish color. How/where to
do that.  (Googling said to change it in the "SciTEGlobal.properties" file, but nothing in there resembles what I'm trying to do. !?!?)

#2: So, specific to HTML files, as I scrolled down thru a file, the background in HTML sections would have this same light-yellowish color, and the JS sections had white background, and I'd like to have something equivalent
to that. (On the defaults I see now, html sections are white, but the JS section are an off-white, but they are
so close to white, that my eye can hardly discern them, unless I tip the laptop's screen back and forth. (Yuck.)

#3: A new behavior I see now, is that there is some scheme for html, that uses different font-sizes for different contexts.  While that seems like a worthwhile feature for many, I'd like to go back to what I had before...where
all lines were the same font-size.  (And then, how can I specify just one single font-size, for all lines in all file-types.)

TIA...

Dave

Comment: The [SciTE Docs](https://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDoc.html) provide all the necessary information in exhaustive detail.

Answer (score 3):

Default background color and style can found in `SciTEGlobal.properties` file

```
# Global default styles for all languages
# Default
style.*.32=$(font.base)
# Line number
style.*.33=back:#E7E7E7,$(font.base)
```

To change default background color open `SciTEUser.properties` file and add following lines

```
# Global default styles for all languages
# Default
style.*.32=$(font.base),back:#101010,fore:#BBBBDD
# Line number
style.*.33=$(font.base),back:#101010
```

Note: Editing `SciTEUser.properties` file for customization is best practice. However this file is stored under %USERPROFILE% folder (in Windows) and customization limited to that machine only. If your SciTE installation is on USB stick (Portable installation) and you want to retain SciTE customization on whichever PC you plugged in then edit `SciTEGlobal.properties`

To do any changes specific to any language then edit `<language>.properties` file.
example `html.properties` for `HTML` specific customization.

Comment: [here](https://dreamcloud.artark.ca/scite-dark-theme/) is dark theme for **SciTE**.